# connecting javascript file with signalR

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I want to connect simple javascript file with .net core webapi made with signalR.

A code demo for above question, with proper solution.

How to connect simple javascript file with signalR .netcore WebApi.

If Solution provided in short and simple form,it will be helpful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.